Request for inertial values for ABB IRB 1600 1.45 10kg robot
I am currently working on integrating the 1.45m ABB IRB 1600 manipulator into Gazebo Ignition Fortress for simulation using ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04, with Python 3.10. However, I am encountering issues with the inertial values for certain links (specifically link_2 and link_6), where the simulation throws an error related to invalid inertia matrices.
I have tried adjusting the values, but the errors persist, and I need the correct values for all the links. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone can provide the correct or recommended inertial values for this robot or guidance on how to properly set these values in the URDF file for Gazebo.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
